# Mist/EthereumWallet error: Method 'eth_sendTransaction' not allowed

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to deploy a smart contract on a private ethereum blockchain and I get this error message "**Method 'eth_sendTransaction' not allowed**" whenever I try to submit a transaction for sending ether or even for creating the contract through the mist integrated Remix IDE.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start your node with the eth api .

Geth --rpc "eth,personal,.."

And unlock your account.